# Subsequence of $G$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Say we had a sequence or function $$G_x=\frac{1}{x+1}$$ Would $$Y_x=\frac{1}{x+1}$$ be considered a sub sequence. Also, would $$Z_x=\frac{1}{x+2}$$ be considered a sub sequence? I feel that the 2nd one is a sequence for sure, but I am not too sure about $Y_x$

Comment: What is your definition of *sub sequence*?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both $Y_x$ and $Z_x$ *can be* sub sequences of $G_x$. This is of course, dependent on how you define a sub sequence. Let's say we have a sequence $A=1,2,3$. Would the sequence $B=1,2,3$ be a sub sequence to $A$?

About $Z_x$, it is simply $G_x$ with a "shift". Simply,
$$ Z_x = G_{x+1} $$
Which is definitely a sub sequence of $G_{x}$

Comment: Say, If I had 1/x, would 1/sqrtx be a subsequence? I'm just trying to digest information to supplement my understanding.

Comment: Also @talbi, does a subsequence have to be less than it's mother sequence?

Comment: No, the series $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ will not be a subset of $\frac{1}{x}$ as it conains values that aren't in it, for example $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. About "being less", I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you're talking about the sequence length, then it's again, dependent on you're definition. Again, consider the sequence $A=1,2,3 = B$. They have the same length, and they can (again, definition) be sub sequences. For a sequence to be a sub sequence of a different, all that matters is the values, and their order.